# Change wildcard route based off an array from Rails 3 to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 3, I have these:

```
# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = %w(cafe restaurant)
end

# shops_controller.rb
class SpotsController < ApplicationController
  def cafe
  end

  def restaurant
  end
end

# routes.rb
resources :shops do
  resources :reviews, :photos
  member do
    get *Shop::TYPES
  end
end
```

The idea is to generate `get` routes based off the `Shop::TYPES` array:

```
get :cafe
get :restaurant
```

In any case when I create another new type in `Shop`, I won't have to update my routes.

I am upgrading to Rails 4. What is the equivalent to `get *Shop::TYPES`, because I couldn't find the answer?

Comment: When you use the wildcard in rails 4 did you see an error? If yes can you share the output ?

Comment: Just an idea (not tested) what if you iterate through the array with something like `Shop::TYPES.each do |type|` and use this to make `get "/#{type}"` ?

Comment: @codingaddicted output from pow is it couldn't start the app. Not much useful stack trace. That's when I use the same rails 3 code though.

Comment: @codingaddicted I don't want to iterate that way. Because if I could use that syntax in Rails 3, there must be another syntax for Rails 4.

Comment: Ok, I find your question interesting I'm digging in rails code to see if I can find something related: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing

Comment: Maybe a match with a constraint can do the trick: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L515

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

```
resources :shops do
  resources :reviews, :photos
  member do
    get 'cafe'
    get 'restaurant'
  end
end
```

You can also try this [Link](http://jerodsanto.net/2013/01/dynamic-routes-to-static-pages-on-rails/)

Comment: I want it dynamic.